# Where is the Twitter Library for images stored?

Tags: ipad, graphics, twitter, ipados

By this I mean: when I use Twitter or Fenix on iPadOS 16, and go to choose an image to go with my tweet, it displays a whole bunch of images, including a lot from my old iPad - this suggests that it is accessing iCloud, since my current iPad is only 4 days old!

The problem is that I have a couple of images visible in the “On My iPad” option in the files app, but I cannot find anywhere in the “iCloud” option than has all of these old files. I would like to be able to choose these two “On My iPad” images for my tweet, but Twitter and Fenix appear to be looking elsewhere. I hope I’ve explained the problem clearly!

Comment: Please edit this post to just have a question. The answer should be put below in the answer section. Thanks!

Comment: Done! Apologies ;-)

Comment: Very nice edits - thanks! The site can be "peculiar" with some of the "customs"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use a convoluted way around the problem. I viewed the files from the Files app, told Siri to take a screenshot, and selected the screenshot image in my reply tweet.